# Please Help! It seems my tokens are stuck in the contract

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp

here is the etherscan link https://sepolia.etherscan.io/token/0xdf55d43636657aef7a071bf8c3150792e64b1f3f?a=0xdf55d43636657aef7a071bf8c3150792e .

Whenever I import the token to my wallet it shows the name but shows the quantity as 0.

Answer (score 0):

The token contract owns all the tokens itself.

It seems at some point the presale was started, but it was configured to run 5 seconds

```
Function: startPreSale(uint256 _preSalePrice,uint256 duration)

MethodID: 0xf9a81af7
[0]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064
[1]:  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
```